# removing triangle artifacts from overlapping height maps OpenGL

Tags: opengl, heightmap

I have two 100x100 height maps that I am drawing using a triangle mesh. One represents the land height, and the other represents (water + land) height.

I currently draw both meshes on top of each other, and I make the water mesh transparent when the water level is 0.

[image: land and water height map]

But where the land meets the water there are lots of artifacts.

I believe the cause is the water mesh is >= the height of the land mesh so at the edges the water mesh height goes from being > land mesh height to == , the visible slope is actually the water mesh slope and not the land mesh slope.

That said, I don't know any good way to fix it.

---

Note: water level may not be flat so replacing the water mesh with a plane wont work

Comment: "water level may not be flat" - why exactly?

Comment: its for a water simulation so the water levels will dynamically change

Comment: You could still replace water table with a separate mesh, not connected with heightmap mesh..

Comment: it is a separate mesh, I am rendering both the water and the land meshes

Comment: "and the other represents (water + land) height" - why not use water height, without land height? Then the artifacts will go away.